# How can I ignore all children elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

I've this code:

```
$('.div2').mousemove(function(e) {
    var posX = (50 - (e.offsetX) / $(this).width() * 100);
    var posY = (-50 + (e.offsetY) / $(this).height() * 100);
    $('.results').html(posX+', '+posY);
});
```

And this html:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="results"></div>
```

it works only when mouser don't hover items... how can I ignore them, but getting right value?

I've tried:

```
if(e.target != this){
    return true;
}
```

but don't get right value over items...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Use the event attributes `layerX` and `layerY` to get the desired values. The `offsetX` and `offsetY` attributes are always relative to the element that is below the cursor, even though the event is bound to a parent. The same applies to the `target` attribute.

Also, I prefer using currentTarget since it makes your code a bit easier to read and understand without having to trace the origin of `this`.

```
$('.div2').mousemove(function(e) {
    var posX = (50 - (e.layerX) / $(e.currentTarget).width() * 100);
    var posY = (-50 + (e.layerY) / $(e.currentTarget).height() * 100);
    $('.results').html(posX+', '+posY);
});
```

Check out my [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/EfgKN/)